# Remove html element on last line with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>2/"><img src="domain.com/good1.jpg" alt="001.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>3/"><img src="domain.com/good2.jpg" alt="002.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good3.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good4.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
```

Now I want to remove the ahref link on the last line only and I also want to remove `<!--nextpage-->` on the last line. The final result should look like this:

```
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>2/"><img src="domain.com/good1.jpg" alt="001.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>3/"><img src="domain.com/good2.jpg" alt="002.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good3.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><img src="domain.com/good4.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></div>
```

I'm having trouble getting my code to work. Here it is:

```js
var val = '<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>2/"><img src="domain.com/good1.jpg" alt="001.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->\n<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>3/"><img src="domain.com/good2.jpg" alt="002.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->\n<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good3.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->\n<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good4.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->\n';

var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.innerHTML = val;
ele.lastChild.remove();
var a = ele.lastChild;
ele.replaceChild(a.firstChild, a);
alert(ele.innerHTML);
```

Can someone help me fix the code?

Comment: Can you remove the surrounding `a` tag by editing the actual php file (instead of attempting to remove the tag after the html is already generated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val = '<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>2/"><img src="domain.com/good1.jpg" alt="001.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage--><div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>3/"><img src="domain.com/good2.jpg" alt="002.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage--><div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good3.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage--><div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good4.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->';

var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.innerHTML = val;
var children = ele.children;
var lastDiv = children[children.length - 1];
var a = lastDiv.firstChild;
var img = a.firstChild;
lastDiv.appendChild(img);
a.remove();
var childNodes = ele.childNodes;
var comment = childNodes[childNodes.length - 1];
comment.remove();
alert(ele.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easly do it with jquery. refer below code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function removeLine(){

    var ele=$('#main');

    var child =$('#main').children().last();

    var subchild=child.children().first();

    var cnt = subchild.contents();
    subchild.replaceWith(cnt);

    var ele1=$('#main');

    ele1.html(ele1.html().substring(0,ele1.html().lastIndexOf("<!--nextpage-->")));



    console.log(ele1.html());


}


</script>



</head>
<body onload="removeLine()">
<div id="main">
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>2/"><img src="domain.com/good1.jpg" alt="001.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>3/"><img src="domain.com/good2.jpg" alt="002.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good3.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>4/"><img src="domain.com/good4.jpg" alt="003.jpg"/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```